# A real life probability question

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have a probability question (which comes from real life). I think I have a correct answer and would really appreciate if someone could confirm it.

> 8 Poets are set the be studied on a course, 5 will be asked for on the
> paper.
>
> Obviously, if you study 4 poets you be will guaranteed to have studied
> at least one that is on the paper.
>
> However, if you study 3 poets, what are the odds that you will have
> studied none of the five that come up on the paper?

My thoughts are: 5 poets are chosen from a possible 8 to be on the paper, so there are $$ {n \choose 5} = 56$$ possible combinations. Only one of these combinations are the five poets which have not been studied, therefore there is a $\frac{1}{56}$ chance that all five poets you have not studied are asked for (together) on the paper.

Is this logic right? If not could anyone point me in the right direction, sometimes it can be easy to miss things when doing counting/probability questions like this.

Comment: This is indeed correct!

Comment: yes, is correct.